# finding and minimizing merge sort algorithm runtime analysis

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory, mergesort

let's say I have an array of the size n,I want to divine it to k new arrays of the size n/k.-**what's the running time of this step may be?****I thought since when we split an array to 2 we look at it like 2^x=n =>x=log N => O(log n) then it works the same here too: k^(n/k)=n => n/k=log N ****but what's next?**

now I run the bubble sort algorithm on each of the k arrays-O(n^2) and I use a merge algorithm on all the k arrays to make a sorted array of the size n-let's say the merge complexity is O(kn).

In addition I wan't to find a K so that I could minimizing the runtime of the algorithm,how can I do it?I thought taking derivative of the runtime function and finding it's minimum will do,it is the right way?

Comment: Mergesort can be optimized by using insertion sort within the recursive calls. For example if you have 10 elements then use mergesort instead of exploring more nodes.

Comment: @Luai Ghunim Thank you for the information,but I don't wanna change the algorithm,I just wanna find a minimum K to divine the array

Comment: You will do bubble sort on k arrays of size n/k, giving a complexity of O(k (n/k)^2) = O(k n^2 / k^2) = O(n^2 / k). Dividing the array to k new arrays will always take O(n).

Comment: @juvian thank you,but are you sure dividing the array to k new arrays will always take O(n)?because when I divine an array into 2 arrays it will take O(log N)?

Comment: dividing an array into 2 arrays does not take O(log N). You are confusing too much merge sort with what you say you want to do

Comment: Merging `k` arrays that make up a total of `n` items is O(n log(k)), not O(kn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge sort splits the array into successively smaller pieces until it gets down to a bunch of 2-element subarrays. Then it begins to apply the merge algorithm on successively larger subarrays.

Imagine you have an array of 16 elements. The merge sort does its merges like this:

```
8 merges of two 1-item subarrays
4 merges of two 2-item subarrays
2 merges of two 4-item subarrays
1 merge of two 8-item subarrays
```

There are four (log<sub>2</sub>(16)) passes, and in each pass it examines every item. Each pass is O(n). So the running time for this merge sort is O(n * log<sub>2</sub>(n)).

Now, imagine you have an array with 81 items, and you want to merge it using a 3-way merge sort. Now you have the following sequence of merges:

```
27 merges of three 1-item subarrays (gives 27 3-item subarrays)
 9 merges of three 3-item subarrays (gives 9 9-item subarrays)
 3 merges of three 9-item subarrays (gives 3 27-item subarrays)
 1 merge of three 27-item subarrays
```

There are four (log<sub>3</sub>(81)) passes. Each merge is O(m * log<sub>2</sub>(k)), where m is the total number of items to be merged, and k is the number of lists. So the first pass has 27 merges that do 3*log<sub>2</sub>(3) comparisons. The next pass has 9 merges that do 9*log<sub>2</sub>(3) comparisons, etc. It ends up that the total merge is O(n * log<sub>3</sub>(n) * log<sub>2</sub>(3))

You can see that the 3-way merge sort lets you do fewer passes (a 3-way merge sort of 16 items would require only three passes), but each pass is a little more expensive. What you have to determine is if:

n * log<sub>k</sub>(n) * log<sub>2</sub>(k) < n * log<sub>2</sub>(n)

Where `k` is the number of subarrays you want to split the array into. I'll let you do that math.

You have to be careful, though, because asymptotic analysis doesn't take into account real-world effects. For example, a 2-way merge is incredibly simple. When you go to a k-way merge where k > 2, you end up having to use a heap or other priority queue data structure, which has quite a bit of overhead. So even if the math above tells you that a 3-way merge sort should be faster, you'll want to benchmark it against the standard 2-way merge.

### Update

You're right. If you simplify the equation, you end up with the equations being the same. So the computational complexity is the same regardless of the value of k.

That makes sense, because if k = x, then you end up with a heap sort.

So then you have to determine if there's a point where the merge overhead, which increases as k increases, is offset by the decreased number of passes. You'll probably need to determine that empirically.

Comment: first I wanna say thank you,you helped me alot.I was trying to solve the n * logk(n) * log2(k) < n * log2(n) and got to the point where k does not effect the result at all,is it true?I got (log(n)/log(k))*(log(k)/log(2))<(log(n)/log(2)) which brings me to  log2(n)< log2(n)

Comment: @ Jim Mischel it doesn't sound right,and won't make sense to me neither,I'm i not solving the equation right?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally we use mergesort for external sorting algorithms, and the answer to this question has been dominated by one fact.  A mergesort requires streaming data from multiple files and writing to a single one.  The bottleneck is in the streaming, and not in CPU.  If you are trying to stream from too many locations on a disk at once, the disk breaks down and starts to do random seeks.  Your throughput on random seeks sucks.

The right answer on your hardware will vary (and especially if you are using SSD drives), but [traditional Unix sort](http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html) settled on a 16 way merge as a reasonable default.